# how to insert new object in node js array if key not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create data structure like that.

```
Var ans =[{"b":[1,2]},{"g":[100,2]}]
```

I want to create a new object within list if key not exists in list ans.
Else if key exists in one object of ans list then I want to add new values into the object of ans list

For Example:

```
Example 1) new data c:{2000}
```

then

```
Var ans =[{"b":[1,2]},{"g":[100,2]},{c:[2000]}]
```

Example 2) new data g:{50}

then

```
Var ans =[{"b":[1,2]},{"g":[100,2,500]},{c:[2000]}]
```

I am a beginner in node js,  understand array, object concept, but not getting exact logic!
Thanks!

Comment: what is `{2000}` (in javascript)?

Comment: c:{2000} is not a valid declaration in javascript

Comment: You can do `var obj = ans.filter(x=>!!x[searchKey])[0]; obj ? obj[searchKey].push(value) : ans.push({searchKey: [value] })`

Comment: Thanks! @rajesh. Finnaly  i got it using your solution

Comment: @Rajesh One problem i noticed in your solution is, when i  hold search key in variable then i pass but it is treating variable name as search key..         var xyz="testkey"  then if pass xyz in place of search key , so it is search for key 'xyz' instead of 'testkey'

Comment: @AakashKag how are you passing value? Also I'm out right now. Is it fine it's i add answer tomorrow?

Comment: var xyz="tekeyst"
var obj = ans.filter(x=>!!x[xyz])[0]; obj ? obj[xyz].push(55) : ans.push({xyz: [4] })

Comment: instead of "tekeayst" it is search for key xyz, means variable name as key , instead of value in variable

Comment: @rajesh Your help will be  make progress in my work.  I will thankful If possible to quick comment on this issue

Comment: @AakashKag I have added an answer. Also my apologies for `key` mistake. I commented in hurry. I have added 2 approaches. Hope it helps! For any query, feel free to comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following:

#### Logic

- Filter array based on key
- Check if object with mentioned key exists or not.
- If yes, push value to this array.
- If not, create a dummy object and push this object to original array.

Correction, when you do `.push({key: value})`, `key` will be considered as string.

**Alternates**

1. If you are using ES6, `.push({ [key] : value })`
2. Create a dummy object `var o = {}`. Set key and value to it `o[key] = value` and push this object.

**Optimisations**

- Instead of setting value like `obj[key] = value`, since we will be operating on arrays, try `obj[key] = [].concat(value)`. This will enable you to pass value as number or array of values.
- Instead of checking the existence of value in `.filter`, try `Array.isArray` to check if value exists and is of type array.

#### Custom function

```js
function checkAndPush(array, key, value) {
  var filteredList = array.filter(function(o) {
    return Array.isArray(o[key]);
  });

  filteredList.length > 0 ? filteredList[0][key].push(value) : array.push({
    [key]: [].concat(value)
  });
  return array;
}

var ans =[{"b":[1,2]},{"g":[100,2]}]

console.log(checkAndPush(ans, "c", [2,3]))
console.log(checkAndPush(ans, "c", 4));
```

#### Prototype function

```js
Array.prototype.checkAndPush = function(key, value) {
  var filteredList = this.filter(function(o) {
    return Array.isArray(o[key]);
  });
  var dummy = {}
  dummy[key] = [].concat(value)

  filteredList.length > 0 ? filteredList[0][key].push(value) : this.push(dummy);
  //  or ES6: this.push({ [key]: [].concat(value) })
  return this;
}

var ans =[{"b":[1,2]},{"g":[100,2]}]

console.log(ans.checkAndPush("c", [2,3]))
console.log(ans.checkAndPush("c", 4));
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for help. I used my own solution, but your solution help me lot to understand many thing in node js. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with objects as your values

```
ans[key] = ans[key] || []
ans[key].push(value)
```

---

Note, this works because your values will be an array.  If they could be primatives then you would use hasOwnProperty to check.

```
if (ans.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  // Add this to your key somehow
} else {
  // initialize the key with your value
}
```

Comment: if `ans[key]` is a falsy value ? better to use `key in ans`

Comment: @PranavCBalan can you think of any scenario where the list value would be falsey here in this scenario where he is use the key to reference an array of answers?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is nothing but a library built on javascript. You can do anything using javascript type of progmming. However push and pop method should be able to help you to deal with nodejs array.
ans[key].push(value)

Comment: Javascript is a language, not a technology. Node is V8 + LibUV + some other C++ bindings. That said, maybe a code example would help.

Comment: guys this solution is working for me  only if pass key directly                                                           var obj = ans.filter(x=>!!x[searchKey])[0]; obj ? obj[searchKey].push(value) : ans.push({searchKey: [value] }) ,  if i hold key in variable then it is not working.. for exam var xyz="testkey" then if pass xyz in place of search key , so it is search for key 'xyz' instead of 'testkey'